# Group concat with 2 tables with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, group-concat

Im having issues with concat for this MYSQL statement.The data looks like this:

```
> ID: 60abae122046b578881656e1, User: Admin, Server: localhost.local 
> ID: 60abae122046b578881656e1, User: Admin, Server: Test Device
> ID: 60aed69a89eb406cd6eaaf89, User: Steve Madden, Server: wpdesktop01
> ID: 60d09c2990d1887919cc8aff, User: Stu Hope, Server: pf-us1-smd
> ID: 60d09c2990d1887919cc8aff, User: Stu Hope, Server: pfv-us1-smd
> ID: 5d826b16827c0805683af8f5, User: test, Server: pf-us1-ansible
> ID: 5d826b16827c0805683af8f5, User: test, Server: pf-us1-dmz-sftp
> ID: 5c9b585c235ec76b0161c648, User: Rodrigo, Server: pf-us1-dev
> ID: 5c9b585c235ec76b0161c648, User: Rodrigo, Server: pf-us1-ansible
> ID: 5c9b585c235ec76b0161c648, User: Rodrigo, Server: pf-us1-zabbix
> ID: 5c9b585c235ec76b0161c648, User: Rodrigo, Server: pf-us1-sm
```

The idea is to get it looking like this:

```
> ID: 60abae122046b578881656e1, User: Admin, Server: localhost.local, Test Device
> ID: 60aed69a89eb406cd6eaaf89, User: Steve Madden, Server: wpdesktop01
> ID: 60d09c2990d1887919cc8aff, User: Stu Hope, Server: pf-us1-smd, pfv-us1-smd
> ID: 5d826b16827c0805683af8f5, User: test, Server: pf-us1-ansible, pf-us1-dmz-sftp
> ID: 5c9b585c235ec76b0161c648, User: Rodrigo, Server: pf-us1-dev, pf-us1-ansible, pf-us1-zabbix, pf-us1-sm
```

My current statement looks like this:

```
$sql_modal = 'SELECT 
  pf_jc_user_audit.jc_id,
  pf_jc_user_audit.jc_user,
  pf_jc_user_server_ass.system_id,
  pf_jc_servers.hostname
FROM 
  pf_jc_user_audit,
  pf_jc_user_server_ass, pf_jc_servers
WHERE 
  pf_jc_user_audit.jc_id = pf_jc_user_server_ass.jc_id_ass and  pf_jc_user_server_ass.system_id = pf_jc_servers.system_id';
```

I have tried amending with:

```
group_concat(pf_jc_servers.hostname)
```

and then:

```
group by pf_jc_user_audit.jc_id
```

But no luck, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use proper joins with `ON` clauses and aliases for the tables to shorten the code and make it more readable.

Then group by `jc_id` and `jc_user`:

```
SELECT ua.jc_id, ua.jc_user,
       GROUP_CONCAT(s.hostname) AS hostname
FROM pf_jc_user_audit ua
INNER JOIN pf_jc_user_server_ass us ON ua.jc_id = us.jc_id_ass
INNER JOIN pf_jc_servers s ON us.system_id = s.system_id
GROUP BY ua.jc_id, ua.jc_user
```

Comment: Thats great, gets me closer. However, I'm unable to access the "hostname" element anymore from the pf_jc_servers.system_id (s.system_id) table and colomn

Comment: @user2720970 I don't see system_id in your sample data and expected results. Isn't hostname the column that you want to aggregate with GROUP_CONCAT()? What do you mean when you say *I'm unable to access the "hostname"*?

Comment: The example data is there, example: localhost.local, Test Device, etc
But yes, hostname is a column in pf_jc_servers

Comment: @user2720970 my query returns 3 columns: jc_id, jc_user and aggregated hostnames just like your desired output. Isn't this that you want?

Comment: Thats exactly what I want, however, this what I get:

Id: 5ff49f6ad2cdea2c6d13e7da, User: Alexsandro, Servers: 
Id: 5cc0e7b88f594602deecbeda, User: Andy, Servers: 
Id: 5cc1cc852654795f801ccffc, User: Ansible, Servers: 
etc...

PHP Notice:  Undefined index: hostname in ....

Comment: @user2720970 this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7nkVfZyFi9afMrTnUyFfhs/0 (simplified to 1 table without the joins) is what you should get. Isn't this your expected output?

Comment: @user2720970 I added an alias to the column returned from GROUP_CONCAT().